# Getting an error "Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException" in jmeter

Tags: java, connection, jmeter

I am executing load test using JMeter where users are suppose to do *Launch*--*Login*--*clk dashboard Page*--*clk landing page* (the page which come after login i.e. home page) where *clk dashboard* and *clk landing page* are repetitive action for 5 times.

Till 30 users I am not getting any error when i increased users load i am start getting an error as

> Response code: Non HTTP response code:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
>       Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to https://stage.ideas.com refused
>
> ```
> Response headers:
>
>
> HTTPSampleResult fields:
> ContentType: 
> DataEncoding: null
> ```

in sample results.

Could any one suggest why I am getting this error ? Sometimes it works for 100 users and sometimes I am getting an error.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you solve it? If you have the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are getting connection refused, this means that JMeter is not able to connect to your server to perform the required test.

This can happen because :

1. The server is not listening to the port anymore, like it crashed
2. The internet connection went down, on your side, server side, or in the middle
3. Some firewall or proxy or similar component between you and the server is denying connection

Since you're running tests, and spawning a lot of connections from the same ip to the server, I would check the number 3 first, meaning some firewall or proxy is limiting your activity to the server for excessive load or security reasons.

Comment: Thanks Simone. some times working fine for even 100 users...but getting error randomly?

Comment: If it's because of some component "in the net", like the firewalls on your hosting company routers, then we can't predict the behaviour. Usually it's better to run jMeter tests on a controlled environment, that is on a known machine (a local computer for example) on a LAN, or on dedicated machines in a cloud, with one machine running the server and one running jmeter with provisioned thruput etc.. otherwise you're testing all the internet and not only your application.

Comment: I am running the test in controlled environment it self. in response data i am getting error as :"org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://stage.ideas.com refused
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)...." however my application is create database pool mechanism (not creating db connection on Demand)i.e.it creates 100 DB connection and using it from only.