# Kubernetes services

Tags: kubernetes, service

I've setup kubernetes cluster in a ubuntu server using kubeadm. I've created a deployment and exposed the deployment using NodePort service. How to I get to access the API(using the IP of the Ubuntu host server)which is running the pod ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow5gV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IP of your ubuntu machine and as since your service is exposed a Node port so you can do something like

192.168.0.1:**31842**

replace the IP with your ubuntu **host** machine IP.

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Comment: if the above answer worked for you, i would request you mark it as an answer, and if found it helpful upvote for it. that's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I'm facing the below challenge while testing the API using JMeter:                   
                                                                                                                       
Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to 10.0.1.55:31842 [/10.0.1.55] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664979/getting-an-error-response-code-non-http-response-code-org-apache-http-conn-ht

Comment: When I tried to look for the port (31842-NodePort using which the deployment is exposed) using netstat command, I couldn't find the port (31842) listed in the list of all the ports that the the ubuntu host server is listening to